# JTA transaction - will commit close the JDBC connection

Tags: java, transactions, jta

This is my class:

```
@Stateless
public class MyClass {

    @Inject
    UserTransaction tx;

    public void myMethod() throws Exception {
        try {
            // ...
            tx.begin();
            // Call DAOs for DB updates
            tx.commit();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            tx.rollback();
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Will tx.commit() / tx.rollback() close the JDBC connection?

Comment: No, and if you close it explicitly the connection will be put back into connection pool instead of real close (if you use a JTA-compatible `DataSource`).

Comment: Closing the connection is a part of real close right? I mean if I use JTA, then I don't have to close the JDBC connection explicitly right?

Comment: You should always close the connection after use (to make it available for other uses), but JTA will not really close it and put it back into pool in order to save the creation costs for next use. First if you also close the data source then you close the whole pool and all its stored connections physically.

Comment: As you said, once the transaction is committed, the JDBC connection will be release to the pool and that connection can be used by a different transaction. Am I correct? I am using JTA through out my application, so I don't have to explicitly close the connection to get it available to a different transaction. Correct?

Comment: Yes correct. Explicitly closing a connection (i.e. putting back to pool) is not necessary as long as you use JPA or another persistence layer which takes care of connection life cycle. If you directly work with JDBC-objects in self-made DAOs then it is another story.

Comment: And committing/rolling-back is not directly related to closing a connection. That are two different topics.

Comment: If I use plain JDBC with a connection pool, then connection.close() is the only way to release the connection back to the pool right?

Comment: In case of plain JDBC, yes.